# Spring do on startup ingnoring failures

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, startup

I need to perform some work when the spring application is ready, something similar to `@Scheduled` but I want it to perform only once.
I found some ways to do it, such as using `@PostConstruct` on a bean, using `@EventListener` or `InitializingBean`, however, all of these ways does not match my need. If during the execution of this logic something goes wrong, I want to ignore it so the application starts anyway. But using these methods the application crashes.

Of course, I can surround the logic with `try-catch` and it will work. But, is there any more elegant way?

Answer (score 5):

We faced a similar issue with our `microservices` , in order to run code just after startup we added a `Component.`

```
ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>
```

Within the application to make a call to the services just after application startup, this worked for us.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    YourService yourService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

        System.out.println("ApplicationReadyEvent: application is up");
        try {
            // some code to call yourservice with property driven or constant inputs 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is one way that I'm considering. However, I'm curious if I can avoid `try-catch`. Something like `@Scheduled` that does not crash the application when the execution crashes.

Comment: This definitely should. But in this case, I would prefer `try-catch`. I'm hoping that spring has some mechanism that is already present that can help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `@PostConstruct` for implementing a logic, the application is not ready yet, so it kind of contradicts your requirement. spring initializes the beans one by one (with respect to the dependencies between them.

After all it builds up the application context.

When the application context is fully initialized, spring indeed allows listeners to be run. So The listeners is a way to go - when the listener is invoked the application is ready.

In both cases (PostConstruct, EventListener) as long as you're not using try/catch block the application context will fail, because it waits till all the listeners will be done.

You can use `@Async` if you don't want the application context to wait for listeners execution. In this case the exception handling will be done by the task executor. See [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-exception)

Personally I don't see any issue with `try/catch` approach

Comment: Thanks a lot. This sounds like a good point! I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @PostConstruct (as you said) but you must wrap your business in `try catch` and ignore it when it throws an exception.

Sample Code

```
 @PostConstruct
 void init() {

    try {

      //Your business

    }

   catch (Exception e) {   

    //Do nothing Or you can just log          

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, as I've mentioned, this is something that I would like to avoid. :)

Comment: @SergiiBishyr oh sorry I hadn't seen it, I'll look for a new solution to this problem